# Multithread is stopped unexpectedly in Asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I'm trying to scan all files in my Android device. I used a multithread class like this:

```
public class FileScanner {

// subfolders to explore
private final Queue<File> exploreList = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<File>();

private long fileCounter = 0;

List<File> listFile = new ArrayList<File>();

public void count() {
    fileCounter++;
}

public long getCounter() {
    return this.fileCounter;
}

public List<File> getListFile() {
    return this.listFile;
}

int[] threads;

public FileScanner(int numberOfThreads) {
    threads = new int[numberOfThreads];
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i] = -1;
    }
}

void scan(File file) {

    // add the first one to the list
    exploreList.add(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        FileExplorer explorer = new FileExplorer(i, this);
        Thread t = new Thread(explorer);
        t.start();
    }

    Thread waitToFinish = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            boolean working = true;
            while (working) {
                working = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                    if (threads[i] == -1) {
                        working = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });

    waitToFinish.start();
}

public void done(int id, int counter) {
    threads[id] = counter;
}

public boolean isFinished() {
    for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        if (threads[i] == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

class FileExplorer implements Runnable {

    public int counter = 0;
    public FileScanner owner;
    private int id;

    public FileExplorer(int id, FileScanner owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!owner.exploreList.isEmpty()) {

            // get the first from the list
            try {
                File file = (File) owner.exploreList.remove();

                if (file.exists()) {

                    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                        count();
                        listFile.add(file);
                    } else {

                        // add the files to the queue
                        File[] arr = file.listFiles();
                        if (arr != null) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                                owner.exploreList.add(arr[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                // silent kill :)
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        owner.done(id, counter);
    }

}
```

And I call it in my Asynctask:

private class FetchResidualAsynctask extends AsyncTask {
        FileScanner fileMachine;

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        listResidualFileTemp.clear();
        listResidualFileThumbnail.clear();
        listResidualAppAds.clear();
        listResidualAppLeftOvers.clear();
        findAllStorage();
        for (int i = 0; i < listStorage.size(); i++) {
            fileMachine = new FileScanner(20);
            fileMachine.scan(listStorage.get(i));
            listFile.addAll(fileMachine.getListFile());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 
    numberOfFiles = listFile.size();
        Log.i("numberOfFiles", "NUmber: " + numberOfFiles);
        processindex = 0;
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mBtnClean.setText(R.string.btn_rescan);
                mBtnClean.setEnabled(false);
                txtResidualFile.setText("");
                mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressbar.setProgress(0);
                mBtnClean.setText(R.string.btn_stop);
                mBtnClean.setEnabled(true);
                mProgressbar.setMax(numberOfFiles);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.size(); i++) {
            getFilePath(listFile.get(i));
        }

    }
```

The problem is the list of file is returned so messy. As I debugged, the results are different each time I tested. The first time it returns a very little small number of files (ex: 160), next time is quite bigger (1200).

I think the FileScanner fileMachine.scan() hasn't finish yet and force stopped to run to the DoInBackground.

Can anybody help me on this one?

Comment: I want the files are all scanned before the DoInBackground starts to run :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. In general, it's not possible to fire off a bunch of threads and somehow have them "work". Instead, you need to create a pool of threads of a pre-defined size, and parcel a new one out when you have work to do. At some point, a task you want to run on a thread will wait, because there are no threads left. This is expected behavior. To facilitate multiple thread usage, decide on the max number of threads you want in advance, build a threadpool, and only then start doing the work. The training class [Sending Operations to Multiple Threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) describes this in some detail.

Comment: Thank you guys for replying. I find the problem is because I called listFile.addAll(fileMachine.getListFile()); before the function is done. Make a do while to check the status of it and just add when all threads are done.

Answer (score 1):

This looks excessively complicated and full of race conditions. Your main bug is probably that threads are detecting that the queue is empty (and then the thread exits) before it is actually empty... i.e. at one moment in time the queue has become momentarily empty (a thread remove()d the last item) but then a thread adds something back to it.

To wait for your workers to complete... you can use Thread.join() or a Semaphore, rather than that complex unsafe polling you've got there.

Are you even sure there's a benefit to parallelizing something like this? I imagine 20 threads all trying to hammer the filesystem simultaneously don't actually get to enjoy a lot of simultaneous execution. It may even be that the filesystem driver serializes all IO requests!